# LDAP search filter for selecting the groups with a particular member

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to devise a search filter to pull the groups with a particular member.  This works, in that it pulls all groups:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=*))
```

But this doesn't, despite when I look at the full group listing, the "member" list contains an entry that matches the expression:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=*MySurname\\, MyForename*))
```

This even returns no results:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=*MyForename*))
```

Does anybody know how I might be able to get this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to provide a fully distinguished name for the value of the member attribute.

Something like:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=cn=yourusername,OU=Users,DC=Yourdomain,DC=net))
```

-jim

Answer (score 0):

Substring matches using `"*"` is not allowed on distinguished names . As suggested by Jim, use the full DN and it will work